# How is the term “dynamically sized” for slice justifiable, when maximum length of a slice is less than length of the underlying array?

Tags: arrays, go, slice

From [A Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/7):

> An array has a fixed size. A slice, on the other hand, is a dynamically-sized, flexible view into the elements of an array.

How can the slice be called as dynamically sized when it cannot go beyond the size of the underlying array.

Comment: When a slice extends beyond the capacity of the underlying array, a underlying array is allocated and the contents copied.

Comment: @Flimzy: Only for the Go `append` buit-in function.

Comment: @peterSO: Yes, but is there some other way to extend the capacity of a slice?

Comment: @Flimzy: The standard library is a good place to see how it's done. Look at the source code for the `bytes.Buffer` `func (b *Buffer) grow(n int) int` method: https://golang.org/src/bytes/buffer.go. grow grows the buffer to guarantee space for n more bytes.

Answer (score 3):

Even with a cap, a dynamic size is still dynamic: it can range between zero and whatever the cap is.

That said, as [Flimzy noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59235575/how-is-the-term-dynamically-sized-for-slice-justifiable-when-maximum-length-o#comment104683748_59235575), if you use an operation that can "grow" a slice, it always returns a new slice, or takes a pointer to the slice—usually the former—so that the routine that needed to go past the current capacity could allocate a new, larger array<sup>1</sup> and make the slice use that instead of the old array.

That's why `append` returns a new value, and you must write:

```
s = append(s, element)
```

for instance.

(The previous underlying array, if any, is garbage collected if and when it is appropriate to do so.  A nil slice has no underlying array and hence a zero capacity.)

---

<sup>1</sup>The runtime uses `unsafe` and other special tricks to allocate this array, bypassing type-checking, but coordinating with the runtime's own garbage collection code.  Hence it can allocate an array whose size is chosen at runtime instead of at compile time.  The compiler's `new` and `make` and `append` built-ins have access to this same ability.

You can write this same kind of tricky code yourself using `unsafe`, but if you do, you run the risk of having to rewrite your code when a new Go release comes out, if the new Go has changed something internally.  So, don't do that: use `append` or `make` to create the runtime-sized array with the slice data already set up for you.

Answer (score 3):

The size of a Go array is fixed at compile time. The size of a Go slice is set dynamically at runtime.

---

References:

[The Go Blog: Go Slices: usage and internals](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals)

[The Go Blog: Arrays, slices (and strings): The mechanics of 'append'](https://blog.golang.org/slices)

Comment: This is little bit confusing. So once we do some append operation on runtime on a slice, then how does the underlying array gets dynamically re-sized? If the dynamic re-sizing happens at run time, then doesn't the new array size get assigned in run time?

Comment: @sofs1:  If the capacity of s is not large enough to fit the additional values, append allocates a new, sufficiently large underlying array that fits both the existing slice elements and the additional values. Otherwise, append re-uses the underlying array. [The Go Programming Language Specification: Appending to and copying slices](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Appending_and_copying_slices). This happens at runtime.

Comment: "This happen at runtime" contradicts to "The size of a Go array is fixed at compile time". So, Can we assume that the first time array size allocation alone happens at compile time?

Comment: @sofs1: The size of a Go array type is fixed at compile time. The Go runtime built-in `make` and `append` functions for Go slice types have special privileges. They can allocte underlying arrays dynamically at run time.

Comment: @sofs1: I have added two useful references to my answer.

Answer (score -2):

> How can the slice be called as dynamically sized when it cannot go beyond the size of the underlying array.

The *types* are static vs dynamic. An array type is like `[4]byte` - the size is part of the type definition, and therefore set at compile time. Only a `[4]byte` can be stored in a variable of type `[4]byte`. Not a `[3]byte`, not a `[5]byte`. It's static.

A slice type is like `[]byte` - the size isn't part of the type definition, so it is not set at compile time, and a slice of *any size* can be stored in a `[]byte` at runtime. It could be zero-length, it could be a thousand, it could be a four-byte window into a million-length array. It's dynamic.

The size of a slice can also shrink and grow within its capacity at runtime, though the capacity can only change by replacing the underlying array (which, being an array, is of fixed size). This is done automatically behind the scenes by `append`, for example. But, to my understanding at least, this is *not* what makes slices "dynamic"; it's the fact that a slice can be of any size at runtime - it is not known at compile time. That is what defines them as "dynamic" to me.